# change label to a Empty textbox by using jQuery

Tags: jquery, textbox, label

I want to replace a Label with a empty textbox by using Jquery function. Below is the code which I have worked.

```
<label>Label1</label><br />
<input type="button" value="Edit" id="Edit" />
$( "#Edit" ).click( function() {
    $( "label" ).replaceWith( function() {
        return "<input type=\"text\" value=\"" + $( this ).val("") + "\" />";
    });
});
```

[Link](https://jsfiddle.net/p6g4zgd5/2/)

Comment: why not `return "<input type=\"text\"  />";` ? or id or class so you can reference it later on

Comment: @guradio: OP want text of label element as value of input.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar **empty textbox by using Jquery function** ?sorry if i misunderstood

Comment: @guradio: good point. not sure why `$( this ).val("")` for value now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Label do not have value property associated with it. You need to use `.text()` instead of `.val()` to get the text content:

```
$( "#Edit" ).click( function() {
    $( "label" ).replaceWith( function() {
        return "<input type=\"text\" />";
    });
});
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/L07ubejv/)**

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but when I click on the Edit button the text box should be Empty, from the above code, it is replacing the label with text box and the label value is coming in the text box, my requirement is textbox should be empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code:

```
<label id="labelId">Label1</label><br />
<input type="button" value="Edit" id="Edit" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#Edit").click(function () {
        $("Label#labelId").replaceWith(function () {
            return "<input type='text' value='' />";
        });
    });
</script>
```

Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

The #1 rule of anything value related. Try .val() .value and .text(). Then if they all fail, dig deeper.

```
$( this ).text()
```

will get you the current value.

but my recommendation would be to scrap the input and add:

```
<label contenteditable="true">Label1</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [.replaceWith(...)](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) and [.prev(...)](http://api.jquery.com/prev/), even [.clone(...)](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) and [.replaceAll(...)](http://api.jquery.com/replaceAll/), you can...

```
$('#Edit').on('click', function()
{
    // IF YOU WANT TO REPLACE BY THE CURRENT INPUT
    $(this).prev('label').replaceWith(this); // see that I ensure the previous element is a labal
    // ELSE
        // IF YOU WANT KEEP EVENT HANDLERS
        $(this).clone(true).replaceAll($(this).prev('label'));
        // ELSE
        $(this).clone().replaceAll($(this).prev('label'));
        // FI
    // FI
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`return "<input type=\"text\" />";`

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/p6g4zgd5/5/)

Just return like this so that the input is empty you can also add ID or Class so you can reference the input later on when needed like below

`return "<input type=\"text\" class=\"classname\"/>";`